# Need to add comma after every 3 digits using php

Tags: php

I am using cms - megento. I want to display the price value in following format :

add comma after every 3 digits.

**for example :**

```
 $price = 987536453 ;

Need to print like 987,536,453.
```

Comment: have you check my answer

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:**

as another answer suggested, there is a simple way to do this using `number_format`:

```
echo number_format(1234); // 1,234
```

**Original answer:**

try this `str_split`

```
$price = 1234;

$price_text = (string)$price; // convert into a string
$price_text = strrev($price_text); // reverse string
$arr = str_split($price_text, "3"); // break string in 3 character sets

$price_new_text = implode(",", $arr);  // implode array with comma
$price_new_text = strrev($price_new_text); // reverse string back
echo $price_new_text; // will output 1,234
```

Comment: for this solution if the number were to be 1987536453 it would output 198,753,645,3 instead of 1,987,536,453. You can either reverse the string back and forth or use number_format as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: The original answer was buggy, for example it was showing 1234 as 123,4 . so I edited it, and also added the shorter solution from the other answer.

Answer (score 43):

Try using the [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.

By default it prints ',' every 3 digits and cuts decimal:

```
echo(number_format(1234));
```

> 1,234

Comment: why this is not the accepted answer, we'll never know

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to group by thousands

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `number_format` or `money_format` to do this.

number_format - https://www.php.net/number_format

money_format - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: Note that `money_format` has been deprecated and then completely removed in PHP8 and should not be used.